# How to get the input element of a texbox in sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, input

How can I get the input element of a textbox by id in javascript?
I already tried to search through the divs manually, but that seams unpractical. Since the Id is always a bit random, how do I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first way

```
  document.getElementById("ur input text box Id").value;
```

but this will fail if your control in a User control because at run time it will change then try this :

```
   document.querySelectorAll('input[id$="put your input textbox id here"]')[0].value;
```

This will sure get you your text box value

Comment: sy, both seam to be undefined

Answer (score 0):

Use `getInputId()` to get the input id. See this example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    items: [{
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'name',
        fieldLabel: 'Name',
        listeners: {
        added: function() {
            alert( this.getInputId() );
        }
    }
    }]
});
```

Update Sencha Touch:

`Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name="yourname"]')`

Check out the docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.ComponentQuery

Comment: firefox says this function is undefined

Comment: What version of Extjs do you use? Make sure you use `this` in the correct scope. Can you post the code you use?

Comment: I'm using sencha touch(shoud have mentioned it, sry) and this function doesnt seam to be in the documentation of sencha touch